# Looking for a 3d plotting software to help me in studies

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

Im not quite sure how to formulate my search queries so I will try asking the question in a new thread. Sorry if it already exists in some form.

I basically will benefit greatly from a program which can take different functions of the type f(x,y) and give me a good 3d graph.

I looked up some on Google, but they were pretty basic and couldn't graph most of the functions I wanted. For example

(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>+z<sup>2</sup>+6)<sup>2</sup> <= 25(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>)

is the equation of a thoroid, but I cannot seem to find a software that can plot it. Same with most other similar surfaces of revolution, for example. (even spheres).

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!
Also sorry for bad formatting, I'm new here

Comment: Simple but powerful is WinPlot.

Comment: Thank you, will definetely check out!

Comment: For simple queries, Wolfram Alpha is good (and free!).

Comment: Yeah I've been using Wolfram for a while now, but I want also to be able to close in on the 3d model, rotate the camera, plot new points and linesand such minor things which wolfram doesnt allow afaik

Comment: Geogebra handles pretty well 3D representations.

Answer (score 0):

In *Mathematica*, a region (defined by your equation) is rendered:

```
RegionPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 6)^2 <= 25 (x^2 + y^2), 
 {x, -3, 3}, 
 {y, -3, 3}, 
 {z, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

A traditional plot:

```
Plot3D[Cos[x y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it like a programming language? I know only c++ kind of. Or can it be used straight from the get go?

Comment: You learn the language.  Anyone who plans to do anything of value in applied mathematics simply *must* know how to do some programming, but plotting is quite simple, so that won't take much time.

Comment: Thing is I cannot afford to spend much time on side stuff since I need this for a quarter of my subjects right now, and in my free time Im focusing a lot more on OOP. I dont really want to get into applied mathematics, I mostly need it to pass my exams and curiosity. But if plotting is easy then I guess I can try learning it just for the sake of it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687582/5016440) will help you. You just have to declare the functions you want to plot in the form $f(x,y,z)=0$ and then give it as an argument to `plot_implicit`. The example you give would be like this:

```
def f(x,y,z):
    return (x**2+y**2+z**2+6)**2 - 25*(x**2+y**2)

plot_implicit(f)
```

and the result would be:
[image]

The plot is interactive by the way.

**EDIT:**
To plot many functions you would need to change the code a little bit. Using the code from the [answer referred above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687582/5016440), you can do:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def add_figure(ax,f,A1,A2,B):
    for z in B: # plot contours in the XY plane
        X,Y = A1,A2
        Z = f(X,Y,z)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z+z, [z], zdir='z')
        # [z] defines the only level to plot for this contour for this value of z
        #
    for y in B: # plot contours in the XZ plane
        X,Z = A1,A2
        Y = f(X,y,Z)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y+y, Z, [y], zdir='y')
        #
    for x in B: # plot contours in the YZ plane
        Y,Z = A1,A2
        X = f(x,Y,Z)
        cset = ax.contour(X+x, Y, Z, [x], zdir='x')
        #
    # must set plot limits because the contour will likely extend
    # way beyond the displayed level.  Otherwise matplotlib extends the plot limits
    # to encompass all values in the contour.


def plot_implicit(funcs, bbox=(-2.5,2.5)):
    ''' create a plot of an implicit function
    fn  ...implicit function (plot where fn==0)
    bbox ..the x,y,and z limits of plotted interval'''
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax = bbox*3
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    A = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) # resolution of the contour
    B = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 15) # number of slices
    A1,A2 = np.meshgrid(A,A) # grid on which the contour is plotted
    #
    for f in funcs:
        add_figure(ax,f,A1,A2,B)
    #
    # must set plot limits because the contour will likely extend
    # way beyond the displayed level.  Otherwise matplotlib extends the plot limits
    # to encompass all values in the contour.
    #
    ax.set_zlim3d(zmin,zmax)
    ax.set_xlim3d(xmin,xmax)
    ax.set_ylim3d(ymin,ymax)
    #
    plt.show()
```

Note that `plot_implicit` now receives a list of functions, for example:

```
def f(x,y,z):
    return (x**2+y**2+z**2+6)**2 - 25*(x**2+y**2)

def g(x,y,z):
    return x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 5


plot_implicit([f,g])
```

gives the following plot
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I, lets say, plot a different function on the same 3d graph ?

Comment: You should say that your answer deals with matplotlib.

Comment: I posted the whole code so I guess it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graphing Calculator 3D for that. It does not require scripting, it lets you plot multiple graphs on a same axis, and you can zoom in on the 3d model, rotate the camera, plot new points and lines.

Here is the screenshot of thoroid graph with this software:

[Plot of sphere and thoroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWm9h.png)